# Startup disk creator crashes in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bootloader

I have been using this tool since the time I started using ubuntu.
But, suddenly startup disk creator crashes as soon as bootloader files are added to the usb stick.
I dont know why it crashes. Is there any bug? Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Running it from a terminal says...?

Comment: No output at all. Is there any place such logs are located?

Comment: location of log is ~/.cache/usb-creator.log 
and output of relevant lines is at  : http://pastebin.com/G2BPFhCL